# Correct way to specify port address with Firebase?

Tags: node.js, firebase

I am deploying a node.js app through Firebase, and everything works except occasionally when I deploy...

```
firebase deploy
```

...I *sometimes* get an error that the address is in use. My node app has this:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const fs = require('fs');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render("index");
});

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log('Listening ...')
})

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

My workaround is that when I get the error I switch to 5001, until I get the error again, then I switch back to 5000.

Obviously this is sub-optimal.

1. Should I be using some kind of environment variable for the port number?
2. If so, will it also work locally if I run my app with node (the firebase emulator takes too long to start up each time).
3. Alternately, is there a firebase command line command that will kill the server remotely?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot deploy a Node process like the one you have to Firebase, as it is not a suitable host for long-lived socket listeners.

You can either host pure client-side code on Firebase Hosting, or run managed code when combining Hosting with Cloud Functions or Cloud Run as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/serverless-overview).

Also see:

- [Run a web socket on Cloud Functions for Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45741284/run-a-web-socket-on-cloud-functions-for-firebase)
- [How to attach socket.io to google firebase app functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43432132/how-to-attach-socket-io-to-google-firebase-app-functions)
- [Problems connecting to socket.io using firebase functions and express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59769019/problems-connecting-to-socket-io-using-firebase-functions-and-express/59771807#59771807)